# Default constructors in Java

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor

I know I'm asking some serious 101 question here...

I have some class `Foo` and a class `Bar` that extends `Foo`. In `Foo` I have a constructor that takes a set of parameters that it sets to its fields. Deriving classes such as `Bar` will typically not need to modify this. Now my IDE is giving me **"There is no default constructor available in Foo"**. From a bit of Googling this appears to be because "constructors are not inherited". So all nice and well, but how do I now get this to work without duplicating this constructor in every deriving class? I'm assuming there is a more sane approach?

Comment: in simple cases, adding a default constructor in the super class may be good?

Answer (score 84, accepted):

Use the `super` constructor:

```
public Bar(int a, double b, ...) {
    super(a, b, ...);
}
```

Comment: I will suggest to also add a default constructor in Bar so that inheriting classes do not need to repeat stuf necessarily. You can have one more constructor in Bar like public Bar(){super(defaultValA,defaultValOfB,...)}

Comment: No sane defaults in this case

Comment: and this is actually the 'sane' approach. inheriting constructors from super classes would be completely insane, think about abstract classes etc. or the amount of constructors you would have in the standard library (and alot of them would not work properly)

Answer (score 25):

> So all nice and well, but how do I now get this to work without duplicating this constructor in every deriving class?

You do need to duplicate the constructor *signatures* - if you want the subclass to have constructors with the same signatures. But you don't need to duplicate the *code* - you just chain to the superclass constructor:

```
public Bar(int x, int y) {
    super(x, y);
    // Any subclass-specific code
}
```

Of course if you can work out the superclass parameters from a *different* set of parameters, that's fine. For example:

```
public Bar(int x) {
    super(x, x * 2);
    // Any subclass-specific code
}
```

You really need to work out what information is required to construct a `Bar` - *that* should dictate your constructors.

If this is a problem, it's possible that you're overusing inheritance. It's hard to say for sure without any idea of what your *actual* classes are, but you should look at using composition instead of inheritance. It's no panacea, but it can avoid this sort of thing.

Comment: Dammit Jon - I had this one in the bag!

Comment: No overuse of inheritance here; seems like a good warning to include by default on inheritance questions from what I have seen though :)

Answer (score 6):

No, there's no more "sane" approach. If your base class has no default constructor, then you must explicitly call the correct constructor from all the children classes.

Note this doesn't mean children classes need to have the *exact* same constructor than base class. For example this is perfectly valid:

```
class Foo {

    protected int a;
    protected int b;

    protected Foo(final int a, final int b) {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }
}

class Bar extends Foo {

    protected Bar() {
        super(0,0);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is solved with this:

```
class Foo{
       Foo(int a, int b){}
}

class Bar extends Foo{
         //Here must be a constructor OR declare a constructor in Foo without parameters
         Bar(){super(1,1)} //this is an example

}
```

Other solution is:

```
class Foo{
   Foo(int a, int b){}
   Foo(){}
}

class Bar extends Foo{
}
```

Remember that if have a constructor with parameters in the **SuperClass** (in this case Foo), the implicit constructor on the **child class** (in this case Bar), always will have a implicit call to "**Super()**" (always have to be one unless explicit).

Answer (score 2):

This error could also happen because you are calling your super constructor last. You might have to move it to be the first statement:

```
    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager, List<Fragment> fragmentList) {
        mFragmentList  = fragmentList;
        super(manager);

    }

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager, List<Fragment> fragmentList) {
        super(manager); --> this should come first
        mFragmentList  = fragmentList;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

JVM will not provide a default constructor if you have provided one due to design reasons. What you can do define constructor in Bar with same signature and call super().

```
public Bar(int x,int y) {
    super(x,y);
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with "security reasons".

Comment: If a no-arg constructor was exposed by default (and the class's creator didn't take defensive action), it would be possible for someone to inadvertently create an invalid object--an object without enough information to be correct. This may led to security concerns.

Comment: I think you're mistaken the word. It's not a security concern, it's a software design concern.

Comment: Also the child constructor doesn't need to have the same signature as I explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If parameters are not required and/or have default values then you can define default constructor (without parameters):

```
class Foo
{
    public final int DEFAULT_A = 42;
    protected int a;
    protected int b;

    public Foo(final int a, final int b)
    {
        this.a = a;
        this.b = b;
    }

    // Is equal to new Foo(Foo.DEFAULT_A, 0);
    public Foo()
    {
        this.a = this.DEFAULT_A;
    }

}

class Bar extends Foo {}

class PiBar extends Bar
{
    public final int DEFAULT_A = Math.PI;

}
```